# Screwed up gutter install, best next steps?

Tags: gutters, fascia

First I thought it would look alright but on closer look, I see the gutters are not just behind but under the drip edge and have the exposed facia.

- While I paid with CC and can just charge back the money for the installation, how would you suggest this to get addressed now?

To be clear I am talking about functional issues, or any problems this may cause.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Get _what_ addressed? Are you asking about aesthetic or functional problems? (Contractual disputes are off-topic for this site, so only ask about fixing the problem, not coercing someone else into doing so. :) )

Comment: Sorry to be clear, mainly concerned about functional problems this may create. I can deal with aestetic and will handle that with installer, just wondering if that creates a functionality issue?

Some other contractor who messed up work and was back kept trying to tell me the whole roof job was messed up witht hat, of course do not trust him one bit.

Comment: Well, does water go where it's supposed to or not? Get your hose up there. :) For the record, gutters rarely stay entirely behind the lower flange of the dripedge. Because they need to slope, and because roofs aren't usually perfectly level, they necessarily drop below the flange. If the dripedge is installed correctly water falls off the edge and into the gutter anyway.

Comment: It looked to go in there when it rained. Im going to put the paper to cover the floor behind some of the gutter areas I can reach to see if they get wet.

Simply by having the fascia boards exposed it won't create a further problem or jeopardize the whole roof job (if water runs properly into the gutter)?

I looked at some examples and the gutters there do not expose the fascia board and show such a large gap. Is this then just more aestethic or would you change this any other way to prevent potential problems?

An example that looks different :

Comment: Hard to say with what little I can see. I'd probably try to tilt the gutters down tight to the fascia just to close that ugly gap and hide the unfinished fascia.

Comment: Will try to get some better picture this afternoon from a ladder.

- Here an example of what I guess is how it ideally looks without that bug gap
https://imgur.com/a/0L9AYwJ

So I guess by installing the gutters you will always have some exposured fascia but it is supposed t sit tight on it. I see the drip edge within the gutter, it is just the big gap that I am concerned about. 
https://imgur.com/a/GYNVeVW

Thanks

Comment: It's not necessarily supposed to sit tight. Some fascias are set perpendicular to the roof plane, making that impractical (which may be the case here). It's a matter of specific aesthetics here. You could just paint the raw wood and move on with life.

Comment: Ok I will get some more pictures when I can this later afternoon, but it seems the other contractor's "your whole roof job has been destroyed" is mainly BS.

I guess I am also confused if the gutters are supposed to just go sort of behind the drip edge without removing it first, or as in this case inserting the ful drip edge into the gutter.

Comment: @isherwood , was not able yet to get on the ladder and get better pictures as I was gone and just snapped these this AM.

The drip edge goes into the gutters I saw that last time I looked into it, my main concern is the space between the gutters and the fascia boards, and whether that is a major concern for the roof job. I am planning on taping some paper there for when it next rains or with a hose to see if water is actually getting behind the gutters.

I also saw there was water on the underside of the gutters this am as it rained quite a lot

https://imgur.com/a/mJipmcE